# Comparing each value in a vector to all other values based on criteria

Tags: r, vector, compare, criteria

I have a vector of unique values, but I want to get only the ones meeting a specific criteria with at least one other value.
For example, if I have a vector like this one

```
v <- c(1,2,5,6,8,10,15,16)
```

And the criteria I want to meet is all values that have at least one other value in the vector with a difference of 1 between them, the result will be

```
1,2,5,6,15,16
```

I want to be able to do it with different functions. So for this example let's assume I use a function that gives me the absolute difference between two given number:

```
AbsDiff <- function(x,y){
           abs(x-y)
           }
```

So the solution should run the `AbsDiff` function for each value against all other values, and get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of your function:

```
m <- outer(v, v, FUN = function(x,y) abs(x-y) == 1)
v[colSums(m) > 0]
# [1]  1  2  5  6 15 16
```

As you can see, I added a logical check to your function that is TRUE whenever the absolute difference between two values is exactly 1. That makes it easier to extract the relevant indices afterwards.

---

If you want to use your function as it is now, you could do it like so:

```
m <- outer(v, v, FUN = AbsDiff)
v[colSums(m == 1) > 0]
```

That means we do the check for ==1 in the second step.

Comment: Great solution! Works with other functions I'm trying to compare with too.

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as @docendo solution still,

```
v <- c(1,2,5,6,8,10,15,16)
x <- vector()
for(i in v){

  if((i+1) %in% v){
    x[length(x)+1] = i
    x[length(x)+1] = i+1
  }
}

x
```